# MySql: Calculate a value based on multiple sub-queries

Tags: mysql, subquery, entity-attribute-value

I have a query that calculates a value based on several sub-queries. The sub-queries are based on a specific timestamp. I would like to calculate this value for records for many different timestamps. I can't quite figure out how to do it.

The basic formula is (S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd - S11S4CreateSessionRespAccSent) * 100 / S11S4CreateSessionRespAccSent

```
SELECT 
((((select ref_data FROM test.sgw_S5S11 where timestamp = "2013-08-21 00:00:06" and ref_type = "S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd" ) - (select ref_data FROM test.sgw_S5S11
where timestamp = "2013-08-21 00:00:06" and ref_type = "S11S4CreateSessionRespAccSent")) * 100) / (select ref_data FROM test.sgw_S5S11
where timestamp = "2013-08-21 00:00:06" and ref_type = "S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd")) as MyCalc
```

I don't know how to paste in a table so here's a sample of my data in csv format

Here's a sample of my data. (I don't know how to put a table in here so it's in CSV format)

> mykey,timestamp,ref_type,ref_data 1016101,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateSessionReqSent,128042907 1016102,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateSessionRespAccRcvd,127088838 1016103,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateSessionRespRejRcvd,615553 1016104,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateBearerReqRcvd,10047 1016105,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateBearerRespAccSent,9932 1016106,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S5S8CreateBearerRespRejSent,103 1016107,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd,128255390 1016108,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateSessionRespAccSent,127114539 1016109,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateSessionRespRejSent,713325 1016110,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateBearerReqSent,10028 1016111,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateBearerRespAccRcvd,9932 1016112,"2013-08-21 00:00:06",S11S4CreateBearerRespRejRcvd,42

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

This query is awkward because you have stored attributes on separate rows.  This design is called Entity-Attribute-Value, and it's usually a bad idea for a relational database.

The following query might be a little more efficient and easier to write:

```
SELECT (eav.ReqRcvd - eav.AccSent) * 100 / eav.AccSent AS MyCalc
FROM (
    SELECT timestamp, 
     MAX(IF(ref_type='S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd', ref_data)) AS ReqRcvd,
     MAX(IF(ref_type='S11S4CreateSessionRespAccSent', ref_data)) AS AccSent
    FROM test.sgw_S5S11
    WHERE timestamp = '2013-08-21 00:00:06'
    GROUP BY timestamp
  ) AS eav;
```

PS: Use single quotes `'` for string and date literals, not double quotes `"`.  In standard SQL, double quotes are for delimiting table and column identifiers.  MySQL treats the two types of quotes the same by default, but this is subject to SQL_MODE and also won't behave the same way if you ever use another brand of RDBMS.  So it's a good to develop the habit of using quotes in the standard way.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin. Your answer got me a lot further than I was but as I expanded the timestamp to allow for more timestamps it just kept giving the max of all available in each ref_type. In order to get his to work at all, I had to change MAX(IF(ref_type='S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd', ref_data)) to MAX(IF(ref_type='S11S4CreateSessionReqRcvd', ref_data, 0)) because what was being returned by the group by statement was the last iteration which wasn't the proper ref_type.  I think I'm just going to pull all this into a perl script and do it that way but I wanted to thank you.

Comment: I learned a lot from using your approach even though it didn't get me what I was looking for. Thanks again!!!